# Sharesheet from a tableViewCell popover on the ipad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share something to the sharesheet from a button inside a cusom cell on a UITableView thats presented as a popover. I keep getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is .

```
func passToShareSheet(fileName: String, ext: String, stringToWriteToFile: String){
    let fileName = "\(fileName).\(ext)"
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        try stringToWriteToFile.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path as Any], applicationActivities: [])
        vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self
        vc.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(stringToWriteToFile)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

I realize its because this is being called on a UITableViewCell but I have no idea how to do it the correct way? any help?

Comment: You need to change `vc.present` to `theTableViewController.present`. But of course you don't have a reference to that view controller from the cell.

Comment: How do I get a reference to that from the cell?

Comment: May be you can set a weak reference of the tableVIewController to the UItableViewCell when you are loading the UItableVIewCell. Thus you can avoid retain cycle and at the same time can also present the view controller.

Comment: This code should be executed in your view controller, not in the cell.  Use delegation or a closure to have the cell call code in the view controller

Comment: Scan [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+present+uitableviewcell+%5Buitableview%5D)

Comment: Paulw11- How do I do that?

Comment: This function should be implemented by your table view controller, it's much easier to get the cell from the table view controller than the opposite. Then you would be able to present your `vc` from your `tableViewController`.